# Is there a commonly used name for functions formed as products of rational powers?

Tags: functions, terminology

Let $q = (q_1, q_2, \dots, q_n)\in\mathbb Q^n$ and $c\in\mathbb R$, and let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be defined by
$$
  f(x) = c \cdot x_1^{q_1}x_2^{q_2}\cdots x_n^{q_n}
$$
where $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is chosen to exclude any points at which $f$ is singular.  Is there a commonly accepted name used for such a function $f$?

I'm tempted to use something like "rational monomial" or "rational power monomial," but I hesitate to do so since as I understand it, the word "monomial" is typically reserved for the case in which all powers are non-negative integers, so modifying that term by simply adding an adjective doesn't seem kosher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would call this a *Puiseux monomial*, since it's the monomial part of a Puiseux series.

From the Wikipedia article on monomials:

> "In the context of Laurent polynomials and Laurent series, the exponents of a monomial may be negative, and in the context of Puiseux series, the exponents may be rational numbers."

Googling turns up a few places this term is used in the literature, e.g.

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610353.pdf

However I think the meaning should be clear to anyone who knows what a Puiseux series is.

Comment: Indeed this does seem like a reasonably commonly used term according to my own searching.  Thanks!